# Error creating new Maven project in eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

When create a new maven project in eclipse some error occurred:

[image: problems have occurred]

[image: Fails to create project]
[image: pom.xml error]
How can I overcome this error?

Comment: This is way too vague as an SO question. You must at least copy/paste your error as text! Then tell us what you did, what you tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be clear in explaining the problem you faced.
Anyway I will demonstrate the steps in creating a maven project

1. GoTo "File" --> "New" --> "Maven Project" . You will see the below window

[image]

2. Click on "Next".You will see the below

[image]

3. Now if you want a simple maven project choose "maven-archetype-quickstart" . If you want a webapp then choose "maven-archetype-webapp"(type "webapp" in search box and you should find it)
4. Once you have made the selection , click on "next" . You will see the below

[image]

5. For "GroupId" - Add your company/organization name
   For "ArtifactId" - Add your project name
6. Click on "Finish"

Eclipse will now have no problem in creating a maven project for you.

Comment: delete the folder found in this path **~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/** and try a "clean install"

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem but this solution has worked for me

make sure you are online

Right-click your project
-Click on Maven
-Update project

-check Force update snapshots/ Releases

-Ok